# TcpClient NetworkStream DataAvailable False, but not

Tags: c#, tcpclient

So I have read more on this online and haven't found any solution. I know the problem is that my ReadAsync is faster than the connection is sending data. But I don't like to use the Thread.Sleep(1) because maybe 1 is not enough, maybe there is a hiccup in the connection. Anything can happen.

This is my code, sometimes my dataBytes Length == 0. But if I debug and set a breakpoint, there is always data. When I set a Thread.Sleep of 500ms works.

So what is happening is that DataAvailable is sometimes false, while more data is coming.

```
using (var client = (TcpClient)c)
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            do
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[256];
                int read = await stream.ReadAsync(b, 0, b.Length);
                await memory.WriteAsync(b, 0, read);
            } while (stream.DataAvailable && stream.CanRead);

            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] dataBytes = memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

To test this connection I use RestSharp to send an HTTP message to the code above.

My question is, how can I fix this in a way I am not depending on a Thread.Sleep.

Comment: It looks like you want *messaging*, such that you know when each "message" is received and you can process it. That's *not* the abstraction TCP offers, which is a single *endless* stream of bytes, until the connection is closed. If you want messaging, it's up to *you* to implement some form of framing, or move to a higher level protocol that does it for you. `DataAvailable` isn't the solution.

Comment: as a side note: you really shouldn't use a new buffer each time around this loop; it *looks* like you could just use `await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);` here, but if you *must* do it yourself: reuse the buffer between reads, and quite likely: lease that buffer from the array-pool

Comment: What do you suggest to use for a simple web server?

Comment: @Niels Kestrel; it'll get it a lot more correct, in a lot less code

Comment: For a simple web server, definitely build on something that already knows about the Request/Response abstraction that HTTP offers you, rather than build that yourself.

Comment: @Niels seriously: not to put too fine a point on it, but HTTP is *really, really hard*. I mean, sure, it looks simple from the outside, but the devil is in the detail, and the details in HTTP are *much more than you want to know*, if the code above is tripping you up. I can guarantee you that anything you write yourself here is going to be wrong in *so many ways*

Comment: I know HTTP is hard, but this is just an example to test my TCP connection. If these basics already have these issues, I have to find another way.

Comment: @Niels fun fact: Kestrel can also host arbitrary TCP protocols, once again in a way that will be *far preferable* to writing your own network code; see multi-part series here, if you're so inclined: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

`DataAvailable` *doesn't tell you* whether more data is coming; it only tells you whether data is available in the buffers *right now*, and can be useful in deciding whether to do a synchronous read vs an asynchronous read. It should not have any place in a `while` loop that determines the end of the read operation.

If you want to read a socket to the end of the data *ever*, you need to keep reading until `Read` returns a non-positive value (assuming you're not doing zero-length reads for async IO reasons, which you aren't). However, most socket work doesn't involve a scenario where you can just read from start to end in one big chunk, and you are instead required to implement "framing" ([see the second section here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html)), allowing you to detect individual messages (which are *completely different* to individual `Read` calls).

Comment: What do you suggest to use for a simple web server?

Comment: @Niels Kestrel; it'll get it a lot more correct, in a lot less code